# Convert MKMApKit CGPoint to SKView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, sprite-kit, skview

How to convert CGPoint acquired from MKMapKit via

```
[self.myMapView convertCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate toPointToView:self.view]
```

to SpriteKit's SKView coordinate system? (SKView is also full screen as is MapKit's view).

Comment: Note that the toPointToView method _returns_ a CGPoint (given a _CLLocationCoordinate2D_).  I'm not familiar with SpriteKit but maybe the SKView method convertPoint:toScene: will help (after you've gotten the CGPoint from map view)?